# changed permitrootlogin to no, but I can still login as root

Tags: ssh, security

I just created a new server (VM) and I setup SSH, I can login fine.
I created another user account, added it to the admin group and sudo works fine.

Now I want tried to disable the root login, so I edited the /etc/ssh/ssh_conf file with:

```
Host *
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

(The above lines are all the lines that are commented out).

**Note: It didn't have PermitRootLogin so I added it myself manually.**

I am running ubuntu 14.04

I can still login using my non-root account, and I can also login with my root login (it asks for the password and then works fine).

I did restart the ssh service, and I also restarted the entire VM just in case.

What could the issue be here?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -vvv root@<vm-ip>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` instead. `ssh_config` settings apply to the client and `PermitRootLogin` is not applicable to the client (see `man ssh_config for applicable settings).

Comment: good catch, I forgot the "d"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show while sshd_config but - you must to set `PermitRootLogin no` before `Subsystem` option.
Cheers.